# How is it possible to get higher resolution video than 4K on recent model iPhones? (Noob here)

Tags: ios-camera

I first apologize if this question is in the wrong place or is formatted wrong. I am young and this is my first post ever here. I was planning on creating a camera app when I get my macbook but before that I was looking at other cameras and noticed that there is an app that shoots 4000x3000 24fps H.265 video on my iPhone 7 plus. How is this possible? Does the API easily let you choose resolutions above 4K or do you have to use a trick?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not really possible.  An app that's allegedly doing it is interpolating pixels between the actual pixels that the camera is delivering.  That means it's basically making up extra pixels, typically by averaging the colors of nearby pixels.

Comment: The app is called ProMovie and it says that it supports 12MP video, which means it's using the entire sensor. I downloaded the app and did tests and it looks a little better than the 4K video, with less noise smearing, maybe due to the fact that it doesn't resize the image? Would there be any way they're either reading the sensor data manually or using the photo api to achieve this? Also thank you for responding, I appreciate it :)